# How do you install a standalone watchOS app on a real device for testing?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos-6

I can’t seem to find out how to test my standalone watchOS app on a real watch.  This is completely stumping me. Xcode does not list my watch as a target, and Apple documentation doesn’t talk about it either.

Every single example I have seen talks about testing your watchOS apps via the companion app on your iPhone, but none seem to talk about how to do it with a purely standalone app.

Haven’t found anything on Google talking about this either. It seems like such an obvious thing that I can’t believe the information is so elusive.

To be clear, I’m not talking about debugging, which I’m not even sure is possible outside of the simulator. I’m talking about just running it on a real device.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to couple your watch with your iPhone. And you have to connect your iPhone by cable or WLAN to your Mac. Then it is possible to install and debug your standalone watchOS app.